# What is Juha Bach's motivation?

Tags: bleach

For everything Juha Bach is doing in the current Bleach manga, what is his reason for doing so?

Also according to the Bleach wiki his official name is "Yhwach" with no reference to Juha Bach though, so I also wonder about that. What is his canonical name?

Comment: A note: [Our community decided](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/a/307/274) that it **is okay** to ask about things that may or may not have been revealed thus far.

Answer (score 5):

He now holds Hueco Mundo. Should he gain control of Soul Society, there would be no power considered great enough (in his mind) to threaten the Quincy race again. This seems to be my assumption.

Although i'm sure there's some sort of connection that's yet to be revealed to us as well. I speculate this connection due to the fact that Masaki's family is dead and there was no explanation given, unless we are to assume they perished in the Quincy genocides.

Answer (score 3):

> what is his reason for doing so?

It has not been revealed yet. Though it is likely to come out towards the end of the arc.

> What is his canonical name?

He is using and is mostly referred to by others as Juha Bach. "Yhwach" may be a title rather than a name (basing this on the similarity to "Yahwe" - the Hebrew name of god), or a different pronunciation of the same name (in a different script/language).

Though it appears that Juha Bach is a mistranslation of Yhwach (which appears to be the [official name](http://shonenjump.viz.com/node/1095)), as @Zeno [commented](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4045/what-is-juha-bachs-motivation/4053?noredirect=1#comment3289_4053).

Comment: I just looked around and apparently Juha Bach is a mistranslation. The official name is shown on http://shonenjump.viz.com/node/1095 and it's "Yhwach", weird.

Comment: Well, the reason is probably revenge? I mean, the Shinigami *did* genocide-annihilate the entire clan of Quincies.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha - Doesn't sound right to me, not timeline wise and in particular not in view of how he regained his powers. That is, he seems to have been an enemy of the shinigami for a very log time, probably from before the genocides.

Comment: @Oded: According to the "prophecy" or whatever, he recovered his full strength in 999 years, so the timeline matches.

Answer (score 1):

He probably wants to kill The Soul King and rule the world. In one of the chapters. he told his assistant to order the Sternritters to retreat so that they can wait for the Royal Guards to come. Juha Bach is too smart to start a war all because of revenge. He only cares about himself.